How to make own title of the part of text?
I'm trying to create titles for pieces of text that won't appear as the last element at the bottom of the page. I haven't been able to find a method to prevent page breaks directly below the title. How to do this?

Code:
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm,paperheight=11cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\meetingtopsep
\setlength\meetingtopsep{2ex plus0.8ex minus0.5ex}
\newcounter{meetingno}[section]
\renewcommand\themeetingno{\Roman{meetingno}}
\newcommand\meeting{
    \vspace{\meetingtopsep}
    \refstepcounter{meetingno}
    \begin{center}
        \large{Meeting \themeetingno}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
AAAaaa
\meeting
\lipsum[2-2]
\meeting
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}


size commands don't take an argument so   \large Meeting not  \large{Meeting} but you should use a heading here. \subsection (if meetings are numbered within section) or perhaps a new heading based on \part if not.

@DavidCarlisle - chapters, sections, subsections are present in the book. This book has some pieces of text that appear independently from regular sectioning ("Meetings" and "Trials"). This is an old book. Idea from a while ago: Should I try using tcolorbox to solve my problem?

There is also the needspace package.


You can define it as a heading so latex takes care of avoiding bad page breaks, I defined it to be level -1 like \part so it's not really in the normal sectioning heirarchy.
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm,paperheight=11cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\meetingtopsep
\setlength\meetingtopsep{4ex plus0.8ex minus0.5ex}% increased as no longer adding `\begin{center} space
\newcounter{meetingno}[section]
\renewcommand\themeetingno{Meeting \Roman{meetingno}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\meeting{% you need this %
                      \@startsection{meetingno}{-1}{\z@}%
                      {-\meetingtopsep}%
                      {2ex \@plus .5ex}%
                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\centering}%
                      {}%  
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
AAAaaa
\meeting
\lipsum[2-2]
\meeting
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}

